# ODT Termination and driver impedance Question

Tags: impedance, signal-integrity, termination, ddr3

I am analyzing signal integrity between an applications processor and DDR3 modules.I was looking at IBIS models for the device I am using. I was confused because certain IBIS models had "driver impedance" and certain ones had "ODT" - (on-die termination)

In that context, would anyone be able to outline the difference between termination impedance and driver impedance?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The data signals on this interface are bi-directional. It means that the same pins are receivers and transmitters. On-die termination refers to impedance in receiver mode, while driver impedance is when the circuit switches into driver mode and drives the signal.